# Disable and enable a specific monitor

Tags: windows-8.1, display

I have three monitors set up like this:

[image]

I want to be able to disable monitors one and two (turn the power off, or otherwise make them a completely black screen - not the "No signal" screen). Is this possible? My current "method" of doing this is just hitting the power buttons but I'm lazy and I don't want to reach over to push them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/268521/29943 (Windows 7) or http://superuser.com/q/495724/29943 (Windows 8)

Comment: and also http://superuser.com/q/767014/29943 and http://superuser.com/q/406577/29943

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a PowerPoint to do this.

Make a single empty slide that's just black.

Then go to 'SLIDE SHOW' and then 'Set up slide show'.  Set it to run on the monitor you choose.

Make two PowerPoints, then use a batch file to run both at the same time.  Don't forget to save the PowerPoints as PowerPoint Shows, so that they run immediately.

If you have any more questions, just ask.