# Win 10 Dual Monitor Settings

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, external-display, display-settings

I need help with win 10 system to configure dual monitor.

That i trying to achieve is then my monitors goes blank in let say 10 min. I need 1 off them go off and another one to stay on newer go to sleep (or even better to display screensaver)

I have PC with 24inch monitor and 5 inch internal display inside my case. What i want is when main pc monitor goes blank I want my 5inch display stay always on and display time or any other information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I sleep one of the displays on a multi-monitor setup?](https://superuser.com/questions/268521/can-i-sleep-one-of-the-displays-on-a-multi-monitor-setup)

Comment: It looks the same but my problem is different, well I have PC with 24inch monitor and 5 inch internal display inside my case. what i want is when main pc monitor goes blank I want my 5inch display stay always on and display time or any other information. And then I move my mouse i want my main monitor to light up.

Comment: Oh, I see, you probably need to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1431331/edit) your question to add that information, it's important. But doesn't the case come with some kind of software so you can customize that display?

Comment: Building custom PC with Raspberry Pi display connected to hdmi, mounted in front off my case, so there is no software for the display. Display acts as normal PC monitor with touch compatibility. I was hoping maybe someone knows any registry tricks to disable 5 inch from going blank then monitors goes to sleep.